# How to remove "glitches" in the loss graph of training phase?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorboard, training-data

When training a deep learning model, I noticed that the training loss was little weird. There were some "glitches" at certain epochs, as seen in the figure below.

[image]

Please let me know the reasons and how to get rid of them?

Thank you

Comment: No, we really can't, this is not a programming question.

Comment: I mean is there any tuning ways or data shuffling to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

This may be completely normal and due to how the learning process works.

In practice, since using stochastic gradient descend (SGD) you optimize the loss function by approximating the whole-dataset loss landscape with the current minibatch loss landscape, the optimization process becomes noisy and peaked.

In fact, in each iteration, you evaluate the loss obtained by the model on the current minibatch and then update the model parameters based on this loss. However, this loss value is not necessarily the value you would have obtained by making a prediction on the whole dataset. For example, in a binary classification problem, imagine what happens if due to randomness your current minibatch contains only samples of one class A instead of both the classes A and B: the current loss doesn't take into account the class B and you will update the model parameters only based on the results of one class (A). As a consequence, if the next minibatch had to contain an equal number of samples of the classes A and B your results will be worst than usual.

Even if the unbalance among classes is usually addressed by using balanced minibatches or weighted loss functions, more in general you must think that what I described may happen also inside one class. Suppose you have a large heterogeneity inside the class A: your model could update the parameters more based on certain features than others.

For more theoretical aspects, which I really encourage you to read, you can have a look at this: 
http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/